# Limit the number of visible menu entries/items in context menu

Tags: .net, infragistics, contextmenu

I have a popup context menu that is dynamically populated with entries.
It is possible that the number of entries is quite large, so the context menu would take up a lot of space on the screen.

If the number of entries in the context menu is larger than my screen's height I get 2 nice arrows at the top & bottom of my context menu allowing me to "scroll" through the list of available entries.

This feature is quite nice and I would like to take advantage of it: I would like to limit the list of visible context menu entries to ~ 10 and then use the "arrows" to scroll through all the menu entries.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any way of limiting the height/number of visible times for a context menu.

Any ideas?

Atm I am using the Infragistics library ([PopupMenuTool](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2010.1/CLR2.0/html/infragistics2.Win.UltraWinToolbars.v10.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.PopupMenuTool.html)) to help create the context menus.

**Addendum:** It seems that [ContextMenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is something like what I want
but I want the ContextMenuStrip (or something similar) to be a submenu in my popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

maybe scrolable jquery extanion help you: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html 
this is the example that you can rewrite to your needs

Comment: Unfortunately that is not what I want - I want a "scrollable" context menu and not a scrollable list

Comment: @Ando Sorry for my unswer, i have misunderstood you :)

Answer (score 0):

I work for Infragistics and for a few years I was the primary developer on the UltraToolbarsManager component. The PopupMenuTool doesn't have a way to restrict it's height. The size of the drop down is always based on where the user clicked, how many items are in the menu, and how big the screen is.

What advantage does the ContextMenuStrip provide over the PopupMenuTool? If it is the ability to nest menus you are looking for, the PopupMenuTool has this ability as well. Just add another PopupMenuTool to the one you are using as the context menu.

Comment: Hi there Mike.
I am already using the recursive PopupMenuTool ability in my application but was looking for a way of adding the "custom height" feature of contextMenuStrip to my context menu (actually my sub-context menu).

Comment: How do you set the custom height? I tried out a few things and it looks like it can be done by setting the MaximumSize property. There is no equivalent in the PopupMenuTool. You would have to submit a feature request for this functionality: http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Protected/RequestFeature.aspx